# Add automatic baby-language translation for posts

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, fun

I'm specifically interested in adding translation for baby language, look how my son looks confused at the current interface in English:

[image: Simon using SO]!

He even tries to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get away from it, but his fingers aren't long enough yet.

If you don't implement this ASAP, you'll lose the next generation of programmers to a rival site.

**Edit**: Perhaps [this](http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/landing/translateforanimals/) could be adapted for my feature-request.

Comment: Didn't they ban the translator-bot for a year?

Comment: Needs more freehand circles.

Comment: @Downvoter: huh?  see, this is why people should leave a comment with the possible duplicate.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42507/cannot-see-duplicate-votes-when-out-of-close-votes/42557#42557

Comment: @~qu, someone voted to close as a duplicate of a question asked today, crazy meta people...

Comment: It's funny how indistinguishable normal Meta behavior is from April Fools' Day behavior.

Comment: I thought you were asking for a lol-speak translator and almost +1'ed it. Can we have one of those instead?

Comment: It looks like he can manage a Shift+Tab nicely.

Comment: @Arj, I decided not to pay anymore for hosting, but I have all the images... I'll be fixing the ones in my posts gradually

Comment: Aha, too bad. But, [how to find those posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out/76914#76914)? ;-)

Comment: Like this one -- on demand

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pish posh, babies love Stack Overflow as-is -- this is a *known fact!*

http://twitpic.com/18nmbx

[image]

Comment: +1 Two more weeks until my boy is born, and then I can get him started on something simple, like moving the Turtle in LOGO.

Comment: I don't think the senior developer depicted here did read the "related questions" suggestions thoroughly before starting to type.

Answer (score 14):

I, for one, absolutely need this feature implemented. I am so sick of having to open up Google translate to translate SO into my native Klingon before using it. Do you have any idea how complicated it is for a severed head living eternally in an infernal jar to go through the extra clicks and menu navigations of Google translate in addition to the already-infuriating Stack Overflow controls?

It's practically impossible, let me tell you. It's a wonder I can use this website at all through my overactive force of will alone! A lesser head would have given up a year ago, but still I press on in spite of the massive oppression and poor accessibility to post-human users.

Rise up against the oppressive corporocentric majority! Cephalocentrism will be the new way of the world!

Comment: They declined a few requests like this, so I don't really have hope... but I have to try... I have to try for the children that nobody stands up for... won't somebody please think of the children? - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qh2sWSVRrmo

Comment: A severed *Klingon* head? How did you make it though childhood and adolescence?

Comment: Very strong jaw muscles and pilates, like every other eternal severed Klingon head.

Comment: Ahh, pilates. I *knew* there was a special trick to it.

Comment: How many words did you invent in a single answer?

Comment: @alex, approximately 42

Comment: *yIqIm!  'InIgo' montoy'a 'oH pongwIj'e'.  vavwI' DaHoHta'.  yIHeghrup!!*

Comment: @~quack: I don't have a Klingon-to-English translator handy; did you just tell me to prepare to die?

Comment: @mmyers: not at all.  i also didn't say my name, or that you killed my father.  _*whistles innocently*_

Comment: *Hello, my name is ~quack. You ducked my mallard. Prepare to dive.* (Do you have six toes on your left foot?)

Answer (score 7):

Stackoverflow does not cater to infants, and has no plans to do so in the near future.

Please set your infant's bookmarks to [http://www.diaperoverflow.com](http://moms4mom.com/) which I'm sure will meet his needs better than SO.

Comment: Oh, we are already there... but filing a feature-request on stackexchange is way too difficult

Comment: I guess there truly are no Fridays on meta.stackexhcange.com, huh?

Comment: I don't like Diaper Overflow, it is just a big mess.

Comment: yeah that site stinks...

Comment: Besides, the posts there are all just full of crap.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with this ([nor this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42544/provide-some-kind-of-on-the-fly-translation-e-g-french-to-english-closed)) `[feature-request]`, but the [Google Language AJAX API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/) can be used to have inline translations to any language that you'd like, using only Google's resources.

Comment: Even baby language?

Comment: @Dow: they support Dhivehi, Inuktitut, Guarani, Khmer, Oriya, Uighur and Tajik. I'd say that they surely support Rugrats' Baby.

Comment: @voyager: I find it somewhat alarming that in spite of the outlandish-sounding names, I know exactly where four of those languages are spoken and have a fair idea of two more.

Comment: @mmyers: The only one that rings a bell for me is Guaraní, and that one is from this part of the world :S

Comment: Khmer is spoken in Cambodia, Oriya in eastern India, Uighur in central Asia (ok, I can't quite pinpoint it), and Tajik in Tajikistan. Yes, I have a tendency to remember useless information. (And it helps/hurts that culture and language is a big part of the strategy game I work on.)

Comment: Hell if you have an android you can translate SO for animals... http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en/landing/translateforanimals/