# Cannot see duplicate votes when out of close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

When you have close votes remaining, you can always see duplicates used as close votes by pretending you're going to close vote (select the 'exact duplicate' reason) and proceed.  But, after the recent changes to that part of the UI, you can no longer click-through if you are out of votes:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Scaled to 75% because that box is ridiculously big.</sup>

**Feature request:** If a user has enough rep to close-vote, then always allow that user to see duplicates used in other close votes, even if that user has cast their limit of close-votes for the day.

This could be done with a link beside the blue `[4]`, or something else.  I really have little preference on how to make them visible, I just know it would be useful.

Comment: Agree. This is a necessary feature.

Comment: @George: Interesting that you say that, but don't have enough rep to close-vote on any MSOFU.  Are you active on another StackExchange site? (Just curious.)

Comment: No. I just think this is necessary for those who can.

Comment: FHC should be red

Comment: @Downvoter: Since when?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/show-possible-duplicates-in-the-main-post-before-its-closed
and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/show-the-reason-given-for-a-close-vote-before-the-question-gets-closed

Comment: @balpha, since always... I tend to make rules of things that happen a lot

Comment: It also happens when you've already voted on that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not technically completed, *but*, [we now auto-insert comments when you vote to close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate), so you can "see" the votes that way.

Comment: The other completed feature makes this one redundant, and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 5):

This highlights why it's good practice to also indicate the duplicate link in a comment, so both those who *can't* vote to close *and* those who are out of close votes can see the link prior to closing.

Comment: Definitely - posting the link as a comment also means that you can start a bit of a discussion before voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of an aside, but: I'd actually prefer that *anyone* could see the possible duplicates while the question is not closed yet, even those with less than 3k reputation. For those people I now always add a comment warning about the possible duplicate, but not every voter does that.

Even more generic: if anyone could see any of the pending votes (not just the possible duplicates, but also the other close reasons), then that might save people from answering questions that are likely to be closed? (Or, in a few occasions: might get people commenting if they don't agree about the close reason.)

Comment: A good point (and posted elsewhere), but I'm just asking for the restoration of a feature that 3k users used to have and got (accidentally?) removed.

Answer (score 2):

YES, PLEASE!