# Cannot see the duplicate question even when you've already voted

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot see duplicate votes when out of close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42507/cannot-see-duplicate-votes-when-out-of-close-votes)

This is similar to [Cannot see duplicate votes when out of close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42507/cannot-see-duplicate-votes-when-out-of-close-votes), the reason why I cannot see it is different.

First question I saw was [How to add a Hotmail Account to Outlook 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/125410/how-to-add-an-hotmail-account-to-outlook-2007). I edited, then voted to close as `Not a real question` because I honestly I couldn't tell what was being asked. Steps to add a Hotmail account are fairly straight forward and he referenced another "problem" that he didn't mention.

After I voted to close I realized that the question already had another close vote (vote was cast while I was casting my vote) for `Exact Duplicate` of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/125414/hotmail-account).

I propose either being able to see what the duplicate question is (as the other [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42507/cannot-see-duplicate-votes-when-out-of-close-votes) mentioned) or a notification (similar to `1 new answer has been posted`) for when you are casting votes on questions.

[Screen shot http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1339/firefoxscreensnapz002z.jpg](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1339/firefoxscreensnapz002z.jpg)

Comment: Questions have been merged. It was calling out in the night. Letting you all mull over the comments before another mod takes to clearing them.

Comment: @ran, why are you a moderator on meta?

Comment: Who knows. Don't see a need for the rush for it. @dow

Comment: I only asked because I thought mods on other sites were mods here automatically @ran

Comment: No, you're right. But it appears to not be automatic. TheTXI wan't auto-Meta-modded back when he was SU mod either. @dow

Comment: No, never been a mod on Meta. Downvoter did accidentally a word, but the context still kind of reads in that flow of questioning why quack is also not yet a mod. Diamond flash was probably from shutting down so many questions on SU. @arj