# Automatic machine translation of questions and answers

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide some kind of on-the-fly translation - E.g. French to English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42544/provide-some-kind-of-on-the-fly-translation-e-g-french-to-english)
>   [The Stack Exchange Translation Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/the-stack-exchange-translation-project)

We are looking for a Q&A forum that will support the following use case:

1. User A posts a question in Simplified Chinese
2. This question is immediately machine translated into English and the translated text is added to the original question
3. User B answers the question in English
4. The answer is immediately machine translated into Chinese and the translated test is added to the answer.

The purpose is to minimize human translation in order to speed up the communication.

A similar scenario is largely supported by Drupal. Is something similar available in Stack Exchange?

Comment: See [the FAQ entry about English](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't harness the new SE model for your own "forum", even if it did support this - for me, this makes the question a redundant one, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Stack Exchange Translation Project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/the-stack-exchange-translation-project), also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42544/provide-some-kind-of-on-the-fly-translation-e-g-french-to-english) and many others.

Comment: @MrD, It's not redundant, it should be a feature-request though.  I imagine the OP's point is that SE would create and host this site.

Comment: The Google Translate API is your friend.

Answer (score 6):

No, nothing like this is available on Stack Exchange.