# Question locked, but no way to respond

Tags: feature-request, reputation, asking-questions

I added a **FOLLOW-ON** question to [Android: Binding data from a database to a CheckBox in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505751/android-binding-data-from-a-database-to-a-checkbox-in-a-listview) because the question was not fully answered. My permissions do not allow me to add comments, but oddly allowed me to add answers.    [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) summarily taked out my question, with no way to respond to his "Why post this as an answer!?"  My question was not totally off-the-wall or unrelated to the original question, but he was allowed to remove my question and reduce my reputation, with no opportunity to challenge his action.

You should allow a way to challenge a question's deletion.

Comment: If you have a question post it as a **question** not an **answer**.

Comment: You were wrong, the moderator was right. See the [faq]. Calling names just proves you more wrong, in my opinion.

Comment: The comment Bill posted was "This section is for answers.  If you have a question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button." What is unclear?

Comment: Look into a mirror and say the following three times:  "StackOverflow is not a forum."  After the third time a pony will appear.

Comment: @Won't Should not it be a unicorn?

Comment: @kia I'm on team narwhal when it comes to horns.

Answer (score 21):

You're trying to add an extension to a question asked in 2009, but you posted it in the answer section, which is for answers.  Since no one will answer in response to another answer, you're far better off posting a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 13):

Follow-on's are not allowed in answers.  You must use comments for follow-ons, or edit your question if you have more information about it.  If it's not your post, earn 50 reputation points and you will earn the privilege to post comments on any question or answer.

Stack Overflow is not a forum, and it doesn't work like other forums; it is a question and answer site.  The question and answer format greatly reduces the noise you see in other forums, which is why we strictly enforce it.

When a moderator deletes an answer like this, the answer is automatically locked by the system.  We found that people would simply undelete their posts if they were not locked, and it made a lot more work for us.

Comment: note, that they could have disabled single-users from undeleting their posts, but still left in the capability of the community voting to undelete.

Comment: @Lance: All deletions of this kind are backed by one or more community mod flags, so it's not like there isn't at least some community consensus. The error rate on such deletions is very, very low.

Comment: @Lance, not sure if your "they could" implies "maybe they did" or "another choice would have been". So, just in case you don't know: since April 2011, posts deleted by a moderator [can no longer be undeleted by a non-moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/lock-posts-by-default-when-deleted-by-a-moderator/86481#86481).

Comment: @Arjan, I was implying "another choice would have been".  It was the change you linked to that really castrated the __community__ on these sites.

Comment: Oops, @Lance, then please don't look who asked that question. ;-) (I did upvote Michael's comment, but well...)

Answer (score 0):

> You should allow a way to challenge a question's deletion.

There is a way, and you're using it right now.

I was going to vote to close this as a duplicate of the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post that says "don't post questions or comments in answers" — which would be appropriate close-behavior for this site — but apparently there is no such post.