# Can ordinary users with access to moderator tools undelete questions deleted by the Community♦ user?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user, undelete, auto-delete

When moderators delete a post, ordinary users [cannot vote to undelete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77107/172266).  When a question is dead or abandoned, [it may be deleted by the Community♦ user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) (RemoveDeadQuestions, RemoveAbandonedQuestions).  The Community♦ user has a ♦ and the capabilities of a moderator.  Does that mean that ordinary users cannot vote to undeleted such automatically deleted questions, or does this rule only apply to manually deleted questions by human moderators?

Comment: *If your post was deleted by trusted users or by the Community user, it will require three undelete votes to be undeleted* from the deletion FAQ: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that?rq=1