# Dynamic upvote bookmarking

Tags: discussion, feature-request, up-votes, bookmarks

Part of what makes SO such a great resource is the ability to order questions by tab and come across answers to questions you hadn't even thought to ask yet. Some of these answers fill in critical gaps for newbies like myself, and I often upvote the most informative. I only wish it were possible to track and somehow order upvoted question in order to have a knowledgebase specific to certain themes. Perhaps a sophisticated bookmarking apparatus internal to SO for smoother tracking. I know this has been suggested before but I am specifically talking about being able to index and tabulate favorite questions according to the user's preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make questions favorites by clicking the star icon.

Of course, I would appreciate if the favorites tab could be organized by tag, and that we could search inside it (maybe is there a search command like `favorites:` ?)

Comment: There *was* an `infavorites` search option, but that has been dropped [last week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out).

Comment: ok, shame... Anyway, I know we're all developpers, and I love my command line, but I feel like SE sites will improve by having a real badass advanced search page (select multiple tags, filter by votes, rep number, favorited, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The new votes tab takes care of this.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156702/quazi?tab=votes&sort=all

It shows all your upvotes/downvoles/close votes/whatnot.