# Search doesn't work well with URLs

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I try to use SO (or any other SE site) search to find the post with specific URL, e.g. [I try to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html) for http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html on SO.

I get no search results, while there are quite a few [when I use Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html), e.g. [What's the best resource for learning about Evidence-based Scheduling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490007/whats-the-best-resource-for-learning-about-evidence-based-scheduling)

Using URLs in search does make sense when we look for similar threads on the site or when we're looking for specific question/answer where we know the link was used.

Comment: I thought you were referring to [failing to search Markdownified URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out/76914#76914) in which the link text hides the actual URL. But in your example the URL is actually, er, [a plain URL](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/006490f8-8ffa-409d-a9e7-b15c23e8ba96/view-source). That's odd indeed!

Comment: This is being worked on but needs several pieces in place, I'll update once URL search is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search with the `url:` option and it includes the ability to handle wildcards, for example: [`url:"*.joelonsoftware.com*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22*.joelonsoftware.com*%22)

I'll add this to the search page help now that it's baked in/working well, most likely on monday.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is done now. I can search urls inside quotes and the result looks correct.

["http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.joelonsoftware.com%2Fitems%2F2007%2F10%2F26.html%22)

Answer (score 0):

If you go the https://stackoverflow.com/search it will offer you to do a custom search of the site with Google, this [works fine with URLs](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html).

I'm quite sure this is by design, Stack Exchange is thought to be searched by Google (too).

Comment: Why would this be by design?

Comment: @Arjan: Maybe I'm mistaken but what I ment was that the search doesn't find URLs but this is not a bug, just the way it works right now. Is this correct?