# Auto URL replacement

Tags: feature-request

I am not sure when this happened, but willow garage seems to have taken down http://opencv.willowgarage.com/ and there are a large number of links to this when doing computer vision research. I haven't been able to figure out where these links may now map to, or if they have just completely disappeared, but it would be really neat if stack overflow could find a mapping for these instances and fix them so that I don't get link after link after link that is unresolved.

Comment: That are [513 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=opencv.willowgarage.com%2F) that need an edit...I won't spend dev or ops  hours on this...

Comment: It's been moved to http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/software/opencv or http://docs.opencv.org/

Comment: It looks like the wiki (what everyone seems to be linking to) was migrated to http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki , according to this: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2442

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaand that's why linkfarming should be left to search engines.

Answer (score 3):

Please see what we did when Dell bought Quest and torpedoed SQLServerPedia. [Here is the post on meta.dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/dealing-with-sqlserverpedia-link-rot) and [here on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190451/dealing-with-sqlserverpedia-link-rot).

Long story short: we fixed this manually. At the very least you need to figure out if the content even still exists, and if it does, how to map the dead links to the new links, before you even post a suggestion that somebody else needs to deal with it. I'm sure plenty of people will be willing to help, but you need to kind of meet people halfway...