# Searching serverfault, unix.* and askubuntu at once?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, search

Suppose I have a linux administration related question, having in mind some specific Debian box.

Then it often seems reasonable to search all the three communities mentioned above ([serverfault](http://serverfault.com), [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com) and [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)), as either of these can have at least some part of the right answer )

This, of course, could be done with a Google query like

```
[my query] AND ( site:askubuntu.com OR \
                 site:serverfault.com OR \
                 site:unix.stackexchange.com )
```

But I am probably missing some way to set some nice check boxes on the main [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) site -- sth like a missing "*advanced query*" link near the "*search all sites*" box, am I not? Ж:-)

PS. Two related questions:

- [I need a way to search across all of the StackExchange vertical communities. Does this exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/i-need-a-way-to-search-across-all-of-the-stackexchange-vertical-communities-doe)
- [“search all sites” on StackExchange.com not returning results from site-specific search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134499/search-all-sites-on-stackexchange-com-not-returning-results-from-site-specific)